# Java Execution timeout

Tags: java, timeout

I'm trying to solve BaekJoon 12865 problem by Java.
But it evaluates Execution timeout.
There isn't any error in eclipse compiler.
Someone know about problem in my codes.
Please tell me what did i do wrong.
This problem is find Maximum value in K weight by N objects that has V(value) and W(weight).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    class Object implements Comparable<Object>{
        private int W;   //object's weight
        private int V;   //object's value
        private int VbyW;
        public Object(int w, int v) {
            this.W = w;
            this.V = v;
            this.VbyW = v/w;  // value by weight
        }
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object object)
        {
            if (object.VbyW > VbyW)
            {
                return 1;
            }else if(object.VbyW < VbyW){
                return -1;
            }else
                return 0;               
        }
    }
    int N;   // number of object
    int K;   // Maximum of weight that I can have
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    N = sc.nextInt();
    K = sc.nextInt(); 

    //first I got number of objects and Maximum weight

    int W[] = new int[N];
    int V[] = new int[N];
    Object[] obj = new Object[N];
    ArrayList<Object> objs = new ArrayList<>(); 
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        W[i] = sc.nextInt();
        V[i] = sc.nextInt();
        obj[i] = new Object(W[i],V[i]);     
        objs.add(obj[i]);
    } // I'll get all object's value and weight
    
    Collections.sort(objs, Collections.reverseOrder());
    int totalV=0;   
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
    {
        while(K>objs.get(j).W)
        {
            totalV +=objs.get(j).V;
        }
    } // I'll find Maximum value in K weight by objects
    System.out.println(totalV);
    sc.close();
}
```

}

problem site : https://www.acmicpc.net/problem/12865

Comment: You are getting an execution timeout because your program is given only two seconds to solve the problem. It would fail the test otherwise.

Comment: Are you sure about,
``int V[] = new int[N];``
variable K is not used, is it supposed to be,
``int V[] = new int[K];`` ?

Comment: Thank you for replying! but i'm sure `int V[] = new int[N];` is right. I supposed W is object's weight , V is object's value  and N is number of object. I'm still don't know what did i do wrong.

Comment: What happens if while(K>objs.get(j).W)  is never false.  Should this be (K>totalV )?